# How to copy ext. libs to build folder during compilation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I use DotNetZip library and forgot to copy one .dll with my .exe file and that's why I cannot run my exe on another PC or even from other folder. How should look pre(post)-build event like to copy all .dll's from lib folder to release one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How have you referenced the DLL, and where are you copying the exe from?

When you build the project, if the DLL is referenced correctly it should be included in the output folder (usually `Debug` or `Release` depending on the build configuration.

If this isn't happening, in Solution Explorer expand references then right click the reference to the dll and click 'properties'. Change "Copy Local" to true.

Comment: Hm, I have this option. I noticed I took .exe from wrong folder: obj\Release istead of bin\Release.
Thanks.

Comment: Ah that explains it then, the `bin\Release` folder should also contain all of the DLLs your application needs to run.